# Compare Vectors up to a specific index

Tags: vector, rust

I am trying to compare the bytes of a file and check if its true type (magic number) matches his supposed extension.

So far this is my code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn extension(filename: &str) -> &str {
    filename
        .rfind('.')
        .map(|idx| &filename[idx..])
        .filter(|ext| ext.chars().skip(1).all(|c| c.is_ascii_alphanumeric()))
        .unwrap_or("")
}

fn check_file_type(filename: &str, bytes: Vec<u8>) -> bool {
    let map: HashMap<Vec<u8>, &str> = [
        ([0x42u8, 0x40u8].to_vec(), ".bmp"),
        ([0xFFu8, 0xD8u8, 0xFFu8].to_vec(), ".jpg"),
        ([0x89u8, 0x50u8, 0x4Eu8, 0x47u8].to_vec(), ".png"),
        ([0x47u8, 0x49u8, 0x46u8, 0x38u8].to_vec(), ".gif"),
    ]
    .iter()
    .cloned()
    .collect();

    for (k, v) in &map {
        if bytes.eq(k) == true {
            // need eq up to len.
            return v == &extension(filename);
        }
        println!("{:#x?} bytes -> {} file", k, v);
    }
    return true;
}

fn main() {
    // does not work if we add more bytes, of course, hence my question.
    let bytes_buf: Vec<u8> = [0x42u8, 0x40u8].to_vec();
    let check: bool = check_file_type("test.bmp", bytes_buf);
    println!("{}", check);
}
```

**How I should implement the eq function to compare both vectors up to key.len()** (only the 3 or 4 first bytes of variable bytes, not the whole file)

I could do it manually but I am sure there is a more elegant solution, I appreciate a little bit of help here!

*PS: bonus side question, I did not succeed to make a map with arrays [u8] of different size (3 or 4 mainly), it is not possible with Rust? Hence I had to use vectors.*

Comment: Bonus: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=59621374b42f013ad954e28e3016c473

Comment: I almost missed your comment, thanks a lot Stargateur!!

Comment: edit: in fact this map is not made at compilation time, is it? How would you do https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=71847b27c2547d81aa2a5ff6003fa735

Comment: https://docs.rs/phf/0.8.0/phf/

Comment: `expected u32, found &[u8; 2]` and `expected u32, found &[u8; 3]`, I don't think it is possible. I found a solution which is to pad with 0x00 and make a tuple with the length and the [u8].

Comment: well there is some limitation it should be possible using build.rs. Anyway you don't want a hashmap you probably want my solution or a use an array of tuple.

Comment: unrelated question, why do `[1, 2, 3].to_vec()` when `vec![1, 2, 3]` is more idiomatic?

Comment: don't post answer in a question please post it as your own answer

Comment: I didn't dare to answer my own question since I didn't feel that I add much value compared to the excellent answers, but okay!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- match using pattern slice
- Some style improvement
- Strange boolean return

```rust
use std::path::Path;

fn check_file_type<P>(filename: P, bytes: &[u8]) -> bool
where
    P: AsRef<Path>,
{
    let v = match bytes {
        [0x42u8, 0x40u8, ..] => "bmp",
        [0xFFu8, 0xD8u8, 0xFFu8, ..] => "jpg",
        [0x89u8, 0x50u8, 0x4Eu8, 0x47u8, ..] => "png",
        [0x47u8, 0x49u8, 0x46u8, 0x38u8, ..] => "gif",
        _ => return true,
    };

    if let Some(ext) = filename.as_ref().extension() {
        ext != v
    } else {
        true
    }
}

fn main() {
    let check = check_file_type("test.bmp", &[0x42u8, 0x40u8, 0x99u8]);
    assert!(!check);
}
```

Comment: why strange that I return true if extension matches magic number, could you elaborate? Also isnt it else false?

Comment: note that I return true when the extension is in line with the type that the magic number indicates. I really like your solution btw! Thanks!

Comment: cause "check" naming is expected to return true for error, or not a bool, name your function `is_extension_correct()` would be more readable. the behavior you describe doesn't look like what you write in code. Here you return true when it doesn't match and sometime when it's match it's very unclear.

Comment: no I return true if the magic number is not part of the list (unknown format, since I cant list them all), but if the extension is a known type and someone tries to hide a .exe in a .jpeg it will be detected

Comment: I agree, I will rename it to "is_file_ext_matching_magic" thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can compare slices:

```
for (k, v) in &map {
    if &bytes[..k.len()] == k {
        return v == &extension (filename)
    }
    println!("{:#x?} bytes -> {} file", k, v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7e929bac4d8cc1e95b01a62087ebf045)

Note however that there is no guarantee on the order of iteration for a hash map, so if one of your keys is a prefix of another key, then there is no guarantee that it won't confuse them. Eg:

```
let map: HashMap<Vec<u8>, &str> = [
    ([1u8, 2, 3].to_vec(), "long_magic"),
    ([1u8, 2].to_vec(), "short_magic"),
]
.iter()
.cloned()
.collect();
```

may find `"short_magic"` when passed `[1u8, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: I reversed the way I looked at things thanks to your excellent final point, I think its easier to start by checking the file extension and check if bytes correspond to what the file pretends to be, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up building my function, truly appreciate the help from the community, you are awesome!

```rs
// Thanks https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Extract_file_extension#Rust
fn extension(filename: &str) -> &str {
    filename
        .rfind('.')
        .map(|idx| &filename[idx..])
        .filter(|ext| ext.chars().skip(1).all(|c| c.is_ascii_alphanumeric()))
        .unwrap_or("")
}

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures
// NB: magic (number) means file signature
fn is_file_extension_matching_magic(filename: &str, bytes: Vec<u8>) -> bool {
    const WILD: u8 = 0xFC; // unspecified byte, could be anything, just make sure
                           // that it is not one of the already used bytes among magic numbers
    let file_extension = extension(filename);

    // get supposed magic based on file extension
    let v = match file_extension {
        ".bmp" => vec![vec![0x42, 0x4D]],
        ".jpg" => vec![vec![0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF]],
        ".png" => vec![vec![0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A]],
        ".gif" => vec![vec![0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38]],
        ".m4a" => vec![vec![
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x66, 0x74, 0x79, 0x70, 0x69, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x02, 0x00, 0x69, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x73, 0x6f, 0x32, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x34, 0x31,
        ]],
        ".pdf" => vec![vec![0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46, 0x2d]],
        ".avi" => vec![vec![
            0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, WILD, WILD, WILD, WILD, 0x41, 0x56, 0x49, 0x20,
        ]],
        ".mp3" => vec![vec![0xFF, 0xFB], vec![0xFF, 0xF2], vec![0xFF, 0xF3]],
        ".webp" => vec![vec![
            0x52, 0x49, 0x46, 0x46, WILD, WILD, WILD, WILD, 0x57, 0x45, 0x42, 0x50,
        ]],
        _ => return true,
    };
    // check that actual magic from bytes match its supposed magic
    'outer: for magic_bytes in v.iter() {
        for i in 0..magic_bytes.len() - 1 {
            //println!("{:x} ", magic_bytes[i]);
            if magic_bytes[i] ^ bytes[i] != 0 && magic_bytes[i] != WILD {
                continue 'outer;
            }
        }
        if magic_bytes[magic_bytes.len() - 1] ^ bytes[magic_bytes.len() - 1] == 0 {
            return true;
        }
    }
    println!(
        "{} with {} ext does not have magic {:x?} matching its extension",
        filename, file_extension, v
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't work: it amounts to only checking the last byte in the magic pattern since the inner loop is a noop. You probably want something like [`continue 'outer`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#break-expressions) to continue the outer loop when encountering a wrong byte.

Comment: No it works, let me explain: for some formats you have many different patterns possible. so in that case I will loop through each pattern, if bytes don't match, I switch to the next pattern, and if bytes matched until the last one, I check with the last one if there is a match, and if so it means that the format is indeed a truthful magic of the pretended type. Don't forget that the function returns false at the end, so continue get you closer to the undesired outcome.

Comment: `test.mp3 with .mp3 ext does not have magic [[ff, fb], [ff, f2], [ff, f3]] matching its extension
false` (original magic given: `[0xFF, 0xAA]`)

Comment: But `test.mp3` with magic `[0x12, 0xFB]` will return `true` because your inner loop always succeeds so it's only checking the `0xFB`.